# Generating unique random elements from MySQL by using rand()

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting elements from MySQL by using this query;

```
select * from bahis where onay='1' or onay='2' order by rand()
```

But elements can be same with this query. For example I have 3 values that matches with this query, A,B,C

it can generate A A B or A B C or A B B

But I want to generate them like A B C or C B A or B A C.

How can I do that?

Comment: I think this is not your complete query. you may have a group by command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, your query will not output any individual row more than once -- it will just return every row in a random order. If you're getting duplicates in the result, then your table must contain duplicates; if this is correct, and you just need to suppress them, use the `DISTINCT` modifier (e.g, `SELECT DISTINCT * ...`).

Answer (score 1):

use something like this

```
select * from 
(select * from bahis where onay='1' or onay='2' group by abc_field) s1
order by rand()
```